# createdCell not Sorting with Data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin datatables to show data from a MySQL database. The code that I use to initialize the datatable is:

```
// Setup the broadcast datatable
var broadcasts = $('#table_broadcasts').DataTable({
  ajax: {
    url: "../assets/php/get_reports_broadcasts.php",
    dataSrc: ''
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'date_approved', title: 'Date Sent' },
    { data: 'subject', title: 'Subject Line' },
    { data: 'name', title: 'Business(es) Approved', searchable: false, createdCell:
      function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        $(td).html('<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-white" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_broadcasts">View Approved</a>');
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

This works as expected in that it displays all of the data except for the last column, instead it displays an anchor tag that ultimately launches a modal. For what it's worth, here is the code that I'm using when launching the modal:

```
$(document).on('click', '#table_broadcasts td a', function() {
  // Get the data at the clicked row
  var data = broadcasts.row($(this).closest('tr').index()).data();
  var subject = data.subject;
  var businesses = data.name;

  // Set the data in the modal
  $('#modal_broadcasts_subject').text(subject);
  $('#modal_broadcasts_businesses').html('<li>' + businesses + '</li>');
});
```

The problem that I am running into is that the data for the respective anchor does not sort with the rest of the data. What I mean by this is that whenever the data comes in, it is sorted on the `date_approved` column in descending order, but datatables automatically resorts the column in ascending order. Whenever I click on the anchor for the first row, the data for the last row is being displayed in the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the error in my code. By removing the `.index()` from when I get the row, it fixed the issue. i.e.

```
var data = broadcasts.row($(this).closest('tr').index()).data(); // Old
var data = broadcasts.row($(this).closest('tr')).data(); // New
```